# Dynamic Class In ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, razor

I use Entity Framework and razor and i have three CategoryModel. These are derived from same base class. First ContentCategoryModel, ProdCategoryModel and NewsCategoryModel.
My question is how can i use just one "foreach loop" for a ArrayList.

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ManageLayout.cshtml";

ArrayList catList = ViewBag.catList;

}

<ul>
/*But ArrayList can contain ContentCategoryModel or NewsCategoryModel or ProdCategoryModel, how can i use this foreach dynamically. because i don't want to use three different foreach*/
    @foreach (ContentCategoryModel cat in catList)
    {
        <li>
            @cat.CategoryName
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: cast them as the base class then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@foreach(var cat in catlist){
    ....
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` just holds objects, so `cat` will be an `object`.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` just holds objects, so you have to cast it to a type to effectively use it.  Since you have a base type you can just cast it:

```
@foreach (CategoryModel cat in catList.Cast<CategoryModel>())
{
    <li>
        @cat.CategoryName
    </li>
}
```

or iterate three times looking for each type:

```
@foreach (ContentCategoryModel cat in catList.OfType<ContentCategoryModel>())
{
    <li>
        @cat.CategoryName
    </li>
}

@foreach (ProdCategoryModel cat in catList.OfType<ProdCategoryModel>())
{
    <li>
        @cat.CategoryName
    </li>
}

@foreach (NewsCategoryModel cat in catList.OfType<NewsCategoryModel>())
{
    <li>
        @cat.CategoryName
    </li>
}
```